# Atom Remote Sync - Upload compiled CSS file when saving Less file?

Tags: css, less, text-editor, atom-editor

I'm a new user of GitHub's Atom and I installed the [less-autocompile](https://atom.io/packages/less-autocompile) package to automatically compile my Less files to CSS. I'm wondering if there's a way I can upload my compiled CSS file to my remote server when saving my Less file.

Right now I'm using Atom's [Remote Sync](https://atom.io/packages/remote-sync) package to upload my files through FTP on save.

When I save changes to my Less file, the actual Less file gets uploaded to my server but what I would like to achieve is that when saving my Less file, the compiled CSS file gets uploaded to my remote server as well.

Right now I have to save the CSS file manually so it gets uploaded, this is breaking my workflow.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just in case I voted to close this question as "offtopic" (-> "searching for a tool").

Comment: The answer is obvious - you need to configure Remote Sync (or find an alternative tool) to watch and upload your CSS files when they are *changed* (as result of Less compilation) not when you *save* them (with or without Atom).

Comment: Do you have any suggestion? Anything that would help me accomplish that?

I've already tried to do it via Remote Sync config and I just can't make it work.

Do you suggest using Grunt or something like that? Any advice or help to guide me in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I'd use `Grunt` or `Gulp` or similar. Simply because as soon as you start to work with modular Less projects (e.g. a main/master less file importing other less files), `less-autocompile` stops making sense too (since the file you'll want to compile is no longer necessary the file you save). In a long run, all these "do this or that with the file you save" editor plugins are easy to start with, but become pretty much useless for real projects.